How do I use constant values on multiple selects in the same script?
I am trying to write scripts that can be used by someone who is not familiar with PostgreSQL. The goal is to validate some reports that use these tables as source. To facilitate, I wanted to use constant variables for the select parameters, something like :
var1 numeric = 123;  
var2 numeric = 022020;
 
select * from table1 t1 inner join table4 t4 on t1.a = t4.a where t1.b = var1 and t1.c = var2; 

select * from table2 t2 inner join table4 t4 on t2.a = t4.a where t2.b = var1 and t2.c = var2; 

select * from table3 t3...

I tried using DO, WITH and TEMP TABLE, but the script doesn't return divided selects, on a format easy to read and change the variables.

It's very unclear what you are trying to do, since your join of t2 and t4 still refers to t1. Also, is this inside a PL/PGSQL script?

I'm sorry, the inner join is just to represent that i am not doing a simple select, on every select I will do an inner join with the same table and use these constant variables to filter values with where. I corrected the mistake.

And I have tried using the DO statement wich I believe requires the PL/PGSQL, but i would prefer to keep it simple, if possible, so i didn't add this part

I think you are looking for the \set command:
cat script.sql

\set var1 123
\set var2 022020

select * from table1 t1 inner join table4 t4 on t1.a = t4.a where t1.b = :var1 and t1.c = :var2;
select * from table2 t2 inner join table4 t4 on t1.a = t4.a where t2.b = :var1 and t2.c = :var2;

Then, you call the script with psql like so:
psql -h ${HOST} -U ${USER} ${DATABASE} < script.sql

If you wish, you can call those \set commands from within psql as well.

I also tried \set but it returns something like
"SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near ""
Position: 1
Error position: line: 1"

@PaolaFarias Did you execute this SQL file using psql? If so, please share this SQL file and the psql-command you use. As an update of your original question.

No, I tried to execute this on DBeaver, as someone will do to validate the reports

I solved it using the "session" variables, so I defined the variable as "set session my.vars.var = '123'" and on the where clause i just defined it as "=current_setting('my.vars.var')::int". Thank you!
